# How deleted result base64 AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What is the code to remove this in an AngularJS directive. Want me to use it for the hide button?

```
angular.module('app', ['uiCropper'])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myImage='';
    $scope.myCroppedImage='';

    var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
      var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (evt) {
        $scope.$apply(function($scope){
          $scope.myImage=evt.target.result;
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };
      angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change',handleFileSelect);
  });
```